# Having issues with GhostScript PDF Conversion

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

I am running The newest version of GhostScript 9.2.1 with the newest Imagick, on Easy Apache 4 on a Centos Box.

I am having issues converting some PDF's to PNG, but not all. I cant seem to identify why. The error I get is:

2017-04-18T12:01:46-04:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.4 Exception convert[55246]: utility.c/ShredFile/1822/Exception
  Failed to remove: /tmp/magick-55246bpeoJy2BkzLf.cache

This is the last line of the convert statement, when running as -debug "ALL". I have tried including the entire Path in the Magick.xml file, which is suggested elsewhere, but that doesnt do the trick. Again, it works most times, but not All.

I can provide a link to the PDF if needed.

Please assist - Thanks.

Jesper

Comment: A little Google will do ya. https://www.google.com/#q=Exception+convert+utility.c/ShredFile/1822/Exception+Failed+to+remove:

Comment: Given that it works 'sometimes' it can't be because IMagick can't find Ghostscript, which is what the Google results I see from your query would suggest. But perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I agree Ken ! - but then what ?

Comment: And bassxzero: This link seems to go another with the exact same issue as me, but with no response.

Answer (score 0):

If you post the PDF somewhere (or just stick a link here as you suggest) I can get it I'll take a look, but the error is not immediately obvious as being due to Ghostscript. That looks like an IMagick error to me, its certainly not GS.

You do know that Ghostscript can render PDF to PNG directly ? Doing so and then opening the PNG in IMagick if you want to work on it further might be a more robust solution.

Comment: I really just need the PNG, nothing more needs to happen with it at this point. I was under the impression that when using GS, Imagic were simply calling GS, and that was the same as using GS directly ?

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by running GS without Imagick. If I ran that with -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 then I would get the same issue, but when I ran it without it, it was fine !